# DataBinding type mismatch

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

So I have no idea why but I get a type mismatch with data binding. I have the exact same code used for data binding in another app and it works fine.
**Error is: Required ActivityMainBinding, Found:ViewDataBinding!**

and if I just delete the assignment to binding, `DataBinding.setContentView` highlights in red saying:
**Not enough information to infer type variable T**

It always worked, I don't know if it's some update or something but I have no idea where to start trying to fix this.

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.pdstudios.practice

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.pdstudios.practice.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main) //PROBLEM HERE
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
```

build.gradle(:app)

```
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pdstudios.practice"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
        viewBinding = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Comment: try creating binding instance like this
 `binding = ActivitySplashBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)`

Comment: But will data binding work with this?

Comment: yes it is working for me

Comment: Okay I found the problem -_- I didn't convert the R.layout.ActivityMain file to be compatible with databinding

Answer (score 6):

Check if you're not missing `layout` tag as your top root layout in your xml file.

Wrap your xml layout in a `<layout></layout>` and DataBindingUtil will work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
```

P.S: If you are not binding your data to xml then do not convert your xml to `<layout/>` tag instead use viewBining for which you dnt have to do anything on xml .